# Swift app failing to build with optimisation on

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Whenever I try to build the application with optimisation level other than `none[-Onone]`, the build fails with the following unhelpful message error: 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

I saw some people wrote that they had written some code that makes the compiler crash. Does anyone have any idea how to find where? Other than commenting out one line at a time?

How do I debug this swift compiler crash?